# Store a complex object in iOS?

Tags: json, swift, plist

I have a complex class object as follows:

```
class Ride {
    var distance:String?
    var price:Double?
    var Legs:[Leg]?
    var Routes:[Route]?
}

class Leg {
    var id:int?
    var value:string?
}

class Route {
    var id:int?
    var value:string?
}
```

What I want is store these as JSON or whatever with values and read and write to it when I needed. My approach was after create Ride object with data serialize to JSON and write to `ridesjson.json` file and then when I want to read from that JSON I want to serialize to Ride object. Can I do this or is there any good way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3, the standard approach to serializing an object to a file is to make it adopt NSCoding (it has to be an NSObject for this to work) and implement `encode(with:)` and `init(coder:)`. Then you can archive to a Data and save that (and reverse the procedure to read it).

```
class Person: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var firstName : String
    var lastName : String
    override var description : String {
        return self.firstName + " " + self.lastName
    }
    init(firstName:String, lastName:String) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        super.init()
    }
    func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(self.lastName, forKey: "last")
        coder.encode(self.firstName, forKey: "first")
    }
    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        self.lastName = coder.decodeObject(forKey:"last") as! String
        self.firstName = coder.decodeObject(forKey:"first") as! String
        super.init()
    }

}
```

Here's an example of archiving it:

```
let fm = FileManager.default
let docsurl = try fm.url(for:.documentDirectory, 
    in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
let moi = Person(firstName: "Matt", lastName: "Neuburg")
let moidata = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: moi)
let moifile = docsurl.appendingPathComponent("moi.txt")
try moidata.write(to: moifile, options: .atomic)
```

Here we unarchive it:

```
let fm = FileManager.default
let docsurl = try fm.url(for:.documentDirectory, 
    in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
let moifile = docsurl.appendingPathComponent("moi.txt")
let persondata = try Data(contentsOf: moifile)
let person = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: persondata) as! Person
print(person) // "Matt Neuburg"
```

In Swift 4, however, it may be easier to use the Codable protocol so as to make your object serializable as a property list or as JSON more or less automatically. Codable works on any type, including a struct. This is all it takes:

```
struct Person : Codable {
    let firstName : String
    let lastName : String
}
```

Here's how to archive a Person:

```
let p = Person(firstName: "Matt", lastName: "Neuburg")
let penc = PropertyListEncoder()
let d = try! penc.encode(p)
```

That's a Data object and you can `write` it directly to disk as in the previous example. Unarchiving is just as simple. Assume `d` is the Data you've read from disk:

```
let p = try! PropertyListDecoder().decode(Person.self, from: d)
```